# How can I hint that a type is comparable with typing

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I want to write a comparison sorting function, I can hint that the input must be a sequence with `Sequence[T]` (or `MutableSequence[T]` in this case).

```
from typing import MutableSequence, T

def comparison_sort(s: MutableSequence[T]) -> None:
    pass
```

However there does not seems to be an out-of-the box way to hint that `T` must be comparable. (There is no `Comparable` or `Ordered` or anything it seems in `typing`.) How can I achieve this? I would like to avoid specifying a specific set of types, like `int`, `float`, `str` so that a user could also hint that their own type is comparable.

Comment: if you are putting it into a function with `sort` in the name isn't it really obvious that the elements need to be sortable?

Comment: also there are no objects that are "Comparable" in that sense, since most objects are able to compare with other objects with same / similar types but not with objects with completely different type, for example `2 < "a"` is invalid but the list could still contain all strings or all numbers.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Type hinting can be used with automated tools to identify problems that might go unnoticed. Sure it may be obvious if you look, but that doesn't mean you looked. For example, maybe the function with "sort" in its name is used in another function that doesn't have "sort" in the name. Automated type checking will pick up non-obvious issues like this that might result from refactoring other code.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen The mutable sequence consists of values that all share a common type. There are no generally comparable types, but there are plenty of types that are comparable to the *same* type, and that's what tahsmith is asking for.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `Comparable` isn't a state of being, it's only meaningful as a descriptor for a pair of types. Usually, a sorting function is working with homogeneous types though, so as long as you don't mind the type checker only handling the concept of "supports `<` with some types" rather than "supports `<` with arbitrary types", you can define your own `Comparable` and bound a `typing` `TypeVar` with it. Conveniently, [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) (which defines `typing` hints) already provides [an example of how you'd do this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound):

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, TypeVar

class Comparable(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def __lt__(self, other: Any) -> bool: ...

CT = TypeVar('CT', bound=Comparable)
```

You can then use this for your `comparable_sort` definition with:

```
def comparable_sort(s: MutableSequence[CT]) -> None:
```

Note that I only required `__lt__` to be defined; as a rule, Python 3 implements its own sorting functions entirely in terms of `__lt__` (it doesn't use any of the other rich comparator operators, not even `__eq__`)<sup>†</sup>, so it's a good idea to design your own algorithm the same way, so anything `sorted` can handle, you can handle the same way.

<sup>†</sup>: Python 2 originally used `__le__` in at least one place (`heapq`), but it's been intentionally, consistently, `__lt__` for the builtins and standard library in the Python 3 timeframe, and your style of typing is Python 3-only anyway.

Comment: don't forget to mention the paragraph below the example: "(Note that this is not ideal -- for example min('x', 1) is invalid at runtime but a type checker would simply infer the return type Comparable . *Unfortunately, addressing this would require introducing a much more powerful and also much more complicated concept,* F-bounded polymorphism. We may revisit this in the future.)" which excellently sums up the issues associated with having a fully working `Comparable` type.

Comment: Hmm is see where my understanding failed. I am expecting things to act like C++ type deduction. it surprised me how min('a', 1) works. I expected it to fail (in mypy checking at least) because the two arguments are of different types, but only one type parameter is used.

Comment: Is it possible to use something other than `Any` in `__lt__`, i.e., something that will match only 'the same' type? Or could we make it generic and use a forward reference string, e.g., `Comparable[T] `and `class UserType(Comparable['UserType']): pass`

Comment: Has this changed yet?

Comment: @minseong: There's still no built-in `Comparable`, and unlikely to be any soon; "we may revisit this in the future" would be a huge change in the `typing` support to date, and I've seen no plans to make any such change.

Answer (score 21):

This version works with the current `mypy` version.

Based on the thread in the `typing` repo: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/59

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import MutableSequence, Protocol, TypeVar


class Comparable(Protocol):
    """Protocol for annotating comparable types."""

    @abstractmethod
    def __lt__(self: CT, other: CT) -> bool:
        pass


CT = TypeVar("CT", bound=Comparable)

def comparison_sort(s: MutableSequence[CT]) -> None:
    pass


comparison_sort([1, 2, 3])  # OK
comparison_sort([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])  # OK
comparison_sort(["42", "420", "2137"])  # OK
comparison_sort([1, 2, "3"])  # mypy error
```

[link](https://gist.github.com/pawelrubin/a394702e4029809f30515621fc41ab1f) to Github gist.

Comment: I'm not sure that type hints for self and other really give any additional safety, because I don't remember any lt that can't compare with the same type.

Comment: and I am certainly in favor of using Protocol for this as you do, not ABC as in the other answer

Comment: I think this can be greatly simplified, no need for `@abstractmethod` for protocols and even bound `TypeVar` seems unjustified.