# How to type-hint "SupportsOrdering" in a function parameter?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I'm trying to implement a function that inverses a strictly monotonically increasing function. Given a value `y` and a strictly monotonically increasing function `f`, the function I'm trying to write would calculate `f_inverse(y)` & return that.

Ideally this should work for any argument-set that has a total ordering defined on it. So it should work for `int`, `float`, `tuple` etc.

So far I have this:

```
def invert_strictly_monotonic_function(y: Any, f: Callable[[Any], Any]) -> Any:
    pass
```

I would like to replace the `Any` with something like `"SupportsOrdering"` - that would tell me that I could rely on the `__eq__` & `__lt__` methods inside this function.

But, of course, `SupportsOrdering` doesn't exist in the `typing` module.

So, how do I go about type-hinting this? Do I need to define my own protocol-type for this? And how would I make that work with something like [`@total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module doesn't provide a comparable type, I think an alternative is defining our own custom type with the use of [typing.protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) as the base class (for structural subtyping) requiring the comparer methods e.g. `__lt__` and `__eq__` with a user-defined `SupportsOrdering`, inspired by these list of pre-defined [protocols](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#protocols) e.g. `typing.SupportsRound`.

### User-defined comparable type:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable, TypeVar


@runtime_checkable
class Comparable(Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    def __lt__(self: SupportsOrdering, other: SupportsOrdering) -> bool:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def __eq__(self: SupportsOrdering, other: object) -> bool:
        pass


SupportsOrdering = TypeVar("SupportsOrdering", bound=Comparable)
```

### Funcionality to test the comparable type:

```
class MyNonComparableClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data


class MyComparableClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __lt__(self: MyComparableClass, other: MyComparableClass) -> bool:
        return self.data < other.data

    def __eq__(self: MyComparableClass, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, MyComparableClass):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.data == other.data


def func(value: SupportsOrdering) -> SupportsOrdering:
    return value
```

### Test 1: Comparable types

```
# Comparable built-ins
func(True)
func(1)
func(1.2)
func("a")
func("abc")
func([1, 2, 3])  # Sequence objects typically may be compared https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types
func((1, 2, 3))
func({1, 2, 3})

# Comparable user-defined class
func(MyComparableClass(1))
```

Output:

```
$ mypy script.py  # Install mypy via <python3 -m pip install mypy>
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

### Test 2: Non-comparable types

```
# Non-comparable built-ins
func({"1": "1"})  # Order comparisons (‘<’, ‘<=’, ‘>=’, ‘>’) raise TypeError. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

# Non-comparable user-defined class
func(MyNonComparableClass(1))
```

Output:

```
$ mypy script.py  # Install mypy via <python3 -m pip install mypy>
script.py:57: error: Value of type variable "SupportsOrdering" of "func" cannot be "Dict[str, str]"
script.py:60: error: Value of type variable "SupportsOrdering" of "func" cannot be "MyNonComparableClass"
```

---

References:

- https://github.com/python/typing/issues/59
- [How can I hint that a type is comparable with typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669222/how-can-i-hint-that-a-type-is-comparable-with-typing)