# Python 3 - type hints for sequences of str

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

Have a function:

```
def f(a: Sequence[str], b: Sequence[str]) -> List[str]:   
    return list(set(a) - set(b))
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['b', 'c']
f(a, b)
```

But this function can be applicable not only for `str` type but for other types that can be comparable (int, float etc). In this case how to set up type hints for `a` and `b` parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37669538/8612463

Comment: Use collections.abc.Hashable instead of str in this case. You may also want type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Any` Type if you are not sure

```
from typing import Any
def f(a: Sequence[Any], b: Sequence[Any]) -> List[Any]:   
    return list(set(a) - set(b))
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['b', 'c']
f(a, b)
```

If you want to make it applicable only to those three types (int, float, str), you should use  Union:

```
from typing import Union
def f(a: Sequence[Union[str, int, float]], b: Sequence[Union[str, int, float]]) -> List[Union[str, int, float]]:   
    return list(set(a) - set(b))
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['b', 'c']
f(a, b)
```

[As of python 3.10](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/) the union type can be omitted and you can write it directly like so:

```
a: Sequence[str|int|float]
```