# NameError occured from type hint

Tags: python, type-hinting

```
def bubblesort(l: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        for j in range(0, len(l)-1):
            if l[j] > l[j+1]:
                l[j], l[j+1] = l[j+1], l[j]
    return l
```

I made a just simple algorithm with a type hint, but the error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Code\AlgorithmStudying\bubble_sort.py", line 1, in <module>
    def bubblesort(l: List[int]) -> List[int]:
NameError: name 'List' is not defined
```

I can't find what is wrong and I know that type hinting is available since Python 3.0 and I'm using Python 3.9.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.9 you don't need to use List (in fact it's deprecated), but if you're going to: did you import it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh Gosh Was it deprecated in 3.9? Then what module do I have to import?

Comment: also `len(list)` is a problem. And your bubble sort code is suboptimal

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/

Comment: you have to import `List` from `typing` module. If you were using `list` then you can directly use it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
import typing

TList = typing.TypeVar('TList', bound=typing.Sequence)


def bubblesort(list_: TList) -> TList:
    """Sorts by comparing and swapping adjacent elements.

    Usage: Suitable for small data sets.
    """
    size = list_.size
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(0, size - i - 1):
            if list_[j] > list_[j + 1]:
                list_[j], list_[j + 1] = list_[j + 1], list_[j]
    return list_
```

Yeah i edited it a couple times now, but i guess i'm fine with it now.
Note: btw not working for strings, since they're immutable.. hmmm.

Comment: any sequence types? you gonna use union of data types?

Comment: For more generic you could define your own `Comparable` — see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37669538/355230).

Comment: @martineau that looks interesting, yes. I try to play with it tomorrow, thx.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are two errors in your code:

1. `def bubblesort(l: List[int]) -> List[int]:` - `List` is *not* a builtin, it comes from the `typing` module. You should do `from typing import List` if you need to use it. **However**, as @jonrsharpe pointed out in a comment, you shouldn't be using `typing.List` anymore; it's deprecated. You should just use `list[int]`.
2. `for i in range(1, len(list)):` - `list`? I think this is a typo, and you mean `l`, the list passed in as a parameter.

So the fixed code should look like this:

```py
def bubblesort(l: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        for j in range(0, len(l)-1):
            if l[j] > l[j+1]:
                l[j], l[j+1] = l[j+1], l[j]
    return l
```